# Is there a way to combine COUNTIF and FILTER?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data that looks somewhat like this:

|  | Alice | Bob | Carla | Dave |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Role** | *Role1* | *Role1* | *Role2* | *Role2( |
| Jan | Activity1 | Activity2 | Activity3 | Activity1 |
| Feb | Activity2 | Activity1 | Activity1 | Activity3 |
| Mar | Activity1 | Activity3 | Activity2 | Activity2 |

I want to count the number of times someone in `Role1` is doing `Activity1`

I can use `Filter` to get the matching array, and I can use `COUNTIF` to filter for a value in a range, but it seems that `COUNTIF` only supports ranges, not arrays

I also know that you could do something like `=COUNT(IF(FILTER($B:$Z, $B2:$Z2="Role1")="Activity1", 1, ""))` but this is giving me "Excel ran out of resources" errors for even small ranges

**Is there an equivalent to `COUNTIF` that works on arrays or some other way to combine these?**

I suspect I'm going to be forced to use a macro, but that seems like overkill

Comment: Have you considered countifs()

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't get `countifs` to work either. I suspect there's a way to use it with `index` or `match` but I can't get that to work

Comment: Not behind a pc, but `SUMPRODUCT()` will probably work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you no need VBA. Sumproduct should work for you. I am writing from my mobile. Give a try on below formula as per screenshot.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:E1="Role1")*(B2:E4="Activity1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, yours is a lot shorter!

Comment: See my "solution" (more of an "whoops"), not sure of the etiquette. I did get `sumproduct` working (using only one `filter`), but I didn't try this even simpler approach

Answer (score 2):

A couple of people suggested `SUMPRODUCT`, which can work. It turns out that my original question also provides a solution that can work: replacing `countif(filter(...))` with `count(if(filter(...)))`

I had tried both of those before posting this question but neither worked for me.

Why?

Turns out I was asking the wrong question. The "Excel ran out of resources" error I was getting was because I had made the assumption that Excel was smarter than it is. By using a range like `$B:$ZZ` I had assumed that Excel would automatically truncate to the cells actually used. That doesn't seem to be the case. When I changed my range to `$B3:$Z30` then the memory errors went away and both of the solutions started working

I'm not sure what the etiquette is here. Do I mark this as the solution, mark P.b. or Harun24HR's answer as the solution, or somehow mark the question as invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTER(FILTER(A:Z,A$2:Z$2="Role1"),(A:A<>"")*(A:A<>"Role"))="Activity1"))`
It filters the data to only show columns with `Role1` and than filters it to lose the empty data and title (even though that would not be necessary for the outcome). Then Sumproduct checks the number of occurances of "`Activity1` in the remaining.

Comment: See my "solution" (more of an "whoops"), not sure of the etiquette. I did get `sumproduct` working, but I managed to do it with only one `filter`)

Comment: I explained the second filter isn't necessary, but I think - even though you sorted out your problem yourself - Harun deserves credit for his answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you’re fine with G-Sheets, just use query function to do this. Way more efficient IMO.